# CMS to run Vue.js gallery

Tags: javascript, cms, vue.js

I'm looking for an (ideally) open-source CMS solution for a photo gallery. Since I am new to `Vue.js` and `.js` in general, I was wondering if there are some that you would recommend?

The functionality would be limited to adding more galleries and photos in the galleries, potentially some references.

**Cheers and Thank you!**